# Parsing a CSV and performing asynchronous tasks on some columns using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a CSV which has placement links and target links in the format 
e.g
**CSV Sample**

```
[placement url],[target url]
[placement url],[target url]
[placement url],[target url]
```

and i need to read the CSV, line by line using javascript and fetch the placement urls's [Page Title] and then post to a PHP script that i already have, each 
**[Page Title]** and its respect **[target URL]**.

So this is what i have for the javascript

```
for (i = 1; i < csvLines.length; i++) {
    csvValues = csvLines[i].split(";");

    pagetitle = csvValues[0];
    target = csvValues[1];
    /*start ajax*/
    $.ajax({

        url:  pagetitle,
        dataType: 'html',
        statusCode: {
            200: function(response) {

                    var matches = response.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
                    placementTitles.push($(matches[0]).text());
                    targetURLS.push(?);



            },
            404: function() {
                  /*404 here*/

            }
        },
        error: function(error) {

        }
    });


    /*end ajax*/

}
```

**My Question**

Which value should i push into targetURLS array on `targetURLS.push(?);`, such that **placementTitles[x]** will always have its respective target URL in **targetURLS[x]**...putting into consideration these operations are asynchronous but still need to maintain the integrity of the CSV by always relating the 2 columns by using the same array index.

Comment: Do you still require help on this?

Comment: Its all good now..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a better solution..
First we store all correlating data in one array [{url, target, response}, {url, target, response}] so the array index is the same for all.

Second we write (or overwrite if you like) our own ajax.get function in which we can add an additional parameter to the callback function (the array index).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            //We write our own $.get to pass a parameter to it
            AJAX = {
                getXmlDoc: function(){return ((window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"))},

                //u:= url, f:= callback, c:=caller (here array index)
                Get: function(u, f, c){
                    var tDoc = this.getXmlDoc();

                    tDoc.open('GET', u, true);
                    tDoc.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        //If you want to check others, change accordingly.
                        if (tDoc.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && tDoc.status === 200) f(tDoc, c);
                    };

                    tDoc.send();
                }
            };
        </script>

        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            var mCSV = ['url;key', 'url;key'];
            var mResults = []; //This will hold our results.

            function test(){
                var mResults = [];
                for(var i=0, j=mCSV.length;i<j;i++){
                    var tS = mCSV[i].split(';');
                    mResults.push({url: tS[0], target: tS[1]});

                    AJAX.Get(tS[0], function(r, i){
                        mResults[i].handled = true;

                        if (r.status === 200){
                            mResults[i].response = $(r.responseText.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[0]).text();
console.log(mResults[i]);
                        };
                    }, i);
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'test()'>

    </body>
</html>
```